# Is it possible read from a file using only FileReader?

Tags: java, filereader

I know the correct approach is

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(FileReader(file));
```

but I checked in the Java API the methods of FileReader class and it has a `read()` method that return the character read. But it's not working for me. I'm reading a file that contains this line of text: "I'm reading a file", and printing it to the screen, but when I run program it prints the equivalent ASCII code for each character.

This is my code:

```
String lectura = "";
try{
    lectura = String.valueOf(fr.read());
} catch(IOException ioex){
    ioex.printStackTrace();
}

while((Integer.parseInt(lectura)) != -1){
    System.out.print(lectura);
    try{
        lectura = String.valueOf(fr.read());
    } catch(IOException ioex){
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is this -

fr.read() is returning an integer and not a character, although that integer returned is the equivalent ASCII code for that character.

When you call String.valueOf() on that integer, the String.valueOf(int i) method gets called, instead of the String.valueOf(char c) method which you are expecting to get called, and therefore it returns the ASCII value as a string, instead of the character value as a string.

So instead, try

```
    lectura = String.valueOf( (char) (fr.read()) );
```

Comment: Almost -- the ints are not ASCII values, FileReader uses the platform's default encoding.

Comment: Well, if the file was written with normal 7-bit ASCII characters there would be no difference. But if a text editor wrote it using latin1 for example, fr.read() would return some int's which weren't valid ASCII codes. (Or it might return nonsense, if `Charset.defaultCharset()` is something like UTF-8.)

Comment: Ok, but now I'm having troubles to stop the reading cicle because I do it with `while(Integer.parseInt(lectura) != -1)` and I get a `NumberFormatException` when the value of `lectura` is not a number and that only happens when the end of the file is reach.

Comment: @Aikanáro you need to check that `fr.read()` did not return -1, and if it did, stop without changing `lectura`.

Comment: Well, this is what I did: <br/> `while(true){if(fr.read() == -1) break; else lectura = String.valueOf((char)fr.read())}`

Comment: Now it's printing a sentence, but not the one I what I wrote on the file. It make no sense what it's printing. It seems aleatory characters.

Comment: @Aikanáro the problem is when you call `fr.read` and check if it's -1, that character has now been read and the `read` call whose result you use will get the *next* character. Just call `read` once, store the result in a variable, and use that variable both in the EOF test and when you actually use the value.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior, text is stored as bytes and each byte has the ASCII value of the character. You can collect these bytes into a byte array and then use new String(array); to convert them into a string. Or you can cast to char to convert individual characters.

Comment: An InputStream reads bytes, a Reader reads characters. (What makes it confusing is that both are encoded as ints.) This is why InputStreamReader needs a Charset; it would be incorrect to just treat the bytes as chars, although it would work for ASCII. You wouldn't want to build a byte array from a Reader and call `new String(byte[])`; you would build a character array and call `new String(char[])`.

Answer (score 1):

FileReader's `read` returns an `int`. You just need to cast this to a `char`.

The reason `Reader`'s `read` doesn't just return a `char` is that using an `int` lets it use `-1` to represent end-of-file.